# Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) execution time : 3.675 s

Tags: c, c99

have any body another way to do this.

I should write a recursive function that finds and returns the length of a connected curve by counting the 'X' letters. The curve is uniquely determined by any starting point (m, n) that is on a curve itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 5
#define N 8
char FELD[M][N] =   {
                    {'X','.','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
                    {'X','X','.','X','.','.','.','X'},
                    {'.','X','.','X','.','X','X','X'},
                    {'.','X','X','X','.','X','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','X','.','.'}
                    };
int arcno ( int m, int n){
    if((m < 0)||(m >= M)||(n < 0)||(n >= N)||(FELD[m][n] != 'X'))
    {
        return 0 ;
    }
    return 1 + arcno (m-1, n) + arcno (m+1, n) + arcno (m, n-1) + arcno (m, n+1);
}
int main(){
    int f = arcno(2, 3);
    printf("arcno = %d \n\n", f);
    for( int m = 0; m < M; m++) { for ( int n = 0; n < N; n++){
    printf("%c",FELD[m][n]);} printf ( "\n" );}
return 0 ;
}
```

I should get 9 but why I get Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 3.675 s

Comment: return 1 + arcno (m-1, n) + arcno (m+1, n) + arcno (m, n-1) + arcno (m, n+1);
this two functions call "arcno (m-1, n) + arcno (m+1, n)" are causing a stackoverflow
you will aways  get m=2; n=3 then m=1 n=3 then m=2 n=3 ....untill your stak overflow

Comment: I noticed that, but I do not know how to handle it

Comment: I had it ^_^ FELD[m][n] = 's';I just have to change the set characters

Comment: that was the mistake I had written 'X' instead of 'x'

Answer (score 1):

I got it ^_^ FELD[m][n] = 's';I just have to change the set characters 
FELD[m][n] = 'x';

```
int arcno ( int m, int n){
    if((m < 0)||(m >= M)||(n < 0)||(n >= N)||(FELD[m][n] != 'X'))
    {
        return 0 ;
    }
    FELD[m][n] = 'x'; //<==========
    return 1 + arcno (m-1, n) + arcno (m+1, n) + arcno (m, n-1) + arcno (m, n+1);
}
```

Comment: that was the mistake I had written 'X' instead of
'x'